# how to point a pointer in a struct to another member of the same struct

Tags: c++

This is my code, I'm trying to point arrayPointer to the array member of the struct:

```
int main()
{

 typedef struct {
     int array[3][2];
     int(*arrayPtr)[2];
 } myStruct;

 myStruct x[2] = 
 {
  { { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} }, .array },
  { { {6,5}, {4,3}, {2,1} }, .array }
 };
}
```

However, I'm getting a "Syntax error before '}' token" compiler error for both the inside lines of the `x[2]` initialization.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? If you're getting compiler errors, give us them. If you're getting unexpected output, tell us the output.

Comment: Im using dev-c++ IDE to test before I put it into the actual code but I get a "syntax error before '}' token" for lines 11 and 12.

Comment: That's really useful information to have. General guideline for asking questions: tell us what you did (wrote that code, tried to compile it), what you expected to happen (it compiled cleanly), and what actually happened (specific compiler error).

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the initialization bit, your array pointer is not of an appropriate type.  This ought to work, however:

```
int main()
{

  typedef struct {
    int array[3][2];
    int (*arrayPtr)[3][2];
  } myStruct;

 myStruct x[2] =
   {
     { { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} }, &x[0].array },
     { { {6,5}, {4,3}, {2,1} }, &x[1].array }
   };
}
```

Comment: Why not? `int(*)[2]` can point to the first member of `int[3][2]`

Comment: Yeah, that works too.  I thought about it, but the OP just said "to the array member".  In that case `&x[0].array[0]` would be the ticket.

Comment: why  int (*arrayPtr)[3][2] and not just int *arrayPtr?

Comment: @alecs because then you'll have to calculate the offsets yourself when indexing the double array.

Comment: why is the '&' in '&x[0].array' needed? Since its a pointer to an array (and I'm pointing to the first element), I thought you don't need the '&'?

Comment: Think about how you create a pointer to an int variable -- even though this is an array, the same concept applies. x[0].array has the type int[3][2] and &x[0].array has type int(*)[3][2] (i.e. a pointer to a int[3][2]).  It just so happens that these two expressions will evaluate to the same address because the address of an array is also the address of its first element.. but if you omit the `&` you will likely get compiler warnings (you might also find compilers that complain about referencing `x` at all here, but that's a whole other issue).

Comment: @FatalError: That's a good point. Referencing `x` in the declaration of `x` is, I believe, categorically undefined behaviour. A compiler seeing that is entirely within its rights to fail to compile, produce a clearly invalid binary, or [launch NetHack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Compiler_easter_eggs).